# Rails 3 validation with unique scope conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I have for example this code in my model validation:

```
  validates :fb_user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :campaign_id}
```

But can occurs that `campaign_id` has value -1 for different users, that raises the validate exception. 
It's possible to do something like this?

```
 validates :fb_user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :campaign_id}, if :campaign_id != -1
```

Can I put a `if conditions` inline in the validates statement or if not possible how can I do the trick?

Comment: Yes you can do that. I don't ever use the new hash syntax so i'd write it like this: `validates :fb_user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :campaign_id}, :if => campaign_id != -1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the idea of MagicMarkker, I have found a solution:

```
validates :fb_user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :campaign_id}, :if => :valCampaign?

def valCampaign?
    if campaign_id == -1
        return false # skip the validation
    else 
        return true  # run the validation
    end
end
```